# Day Summary from JSON and swift

Tags: json, swift

I am abel to get the current and  hourly weather data and based on the following criteria:

viewController:

let dailyWeather = weatherForecast.weekly[0]
                    let hourlyWeather = weatherForecast.hourly[hour + 4]

```
                let weeklyWeather = weatherForecast.weekly

                self.hourlySummaryLabel.text = hourlyWeather.hourlySummary
                self.tomorrowSummary.text = dailyWeather.summary
```

forecast.swift:
struct Forecast {
    var currentWeather: CurrentWeather?
    var weekly: [DailyWeather] = []
    var hourly: [HourlyWeather] = []

```
init(weatherDictionary: [String: AnyObject]){



    if let currentWeatherDictionary = weatherDictionary["currently"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
        currentWeather = CurrentWeather(weatherDictionary: currentWeatherDictionary)

    }

    if let weeklyWeatherArray = weatherDictionary["daily"]?["data"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {

        for dailyWeather in weeklyWeatherArray {
            let daily = DailyWeather(dailyWeatherDictionary: dailyWeather)
            weekly.append(daily)

        }


    }

    if let hourlyWeatherArray = weatherDictionary["hourly"]?["data"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {


        for hourlyWeather in hourlyWeatherArray {

            let hour = HourlyWeather(dailyWeatherDictionary: hourlyWeather)

            hourly.append(hour)

        }

    }

}
```

}

however, i need to get the full day summary from the following json:

```
units = si;
}, "hourly": {
    data =     (
                {
                           {
            apparentTemperature = "33.61";
            cloudCover = 0;
            dewPoint = "12.77";
            humidity = "0.27";
            icon = "clear-day";
            ozone = "279.14";
            precipIntensity = 0;
            precipProbability = 0;
            pressure = "1004.85";
            summary = Clear;
            temperature = "34.66";
            time = 1463464800;
            windBearing = 4;
            windSpeed = "2.48";
        }
    );
    icon = wind;
    summary = "Breezy until this evening."; -----> Need This Summary
```

is there any way to do it?

Comment: What about using `weatherDictionary["hourly"]?["summary"]`?

Comment: i have already tried that, but it return nil